# C# LinkedList Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, multithreading, linked-list

I have this code statement and I run it into a timer, its interval is 50 ms. After `thread1` worked, my linked-list (data) is equal to the Read_Data3. Then I check this condition `if (data.ElementAt(0) == Convert.ToByte('$'))`. However it gives an error that says "Value cannot be null". I checked that arrays and linked-list are not empty. What is the reason of this error? Any idea?

```
thread1 = new Thread(delegate()
{
    Read_Data2 = Read_Data1;
    lastCount = count;
    division = lastCount / 18;
    remaning = (lastCount - 18 * division);

    Read_Data3 = new byte[lastCount - remaning];

    for (int i = 0; i < lastCount - remaning; i++)
    {
        Read_Data3[i] = Read_Data2[i];
    }
    if (remaning > 0)
    {
        Read_Data4 = new byte[remaning];
        for (int i = 0; i < remaning; i++)
        {
            Read_Data4[i] = Read_Data2[lastCount - remaning + i];
        }
    }
    count = remaning;
    if (lastCount - remaning > 17)
    data = new LinkedList<byte>(Read_Data3);
});
    thread1.Start();

if (data.ElementAt(0) == Convert.ToByte('$'))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (lastCount - remaning) / 18; i++)
    {
        //time = new XDate(DateTime.Now);
        if (data.ElementAt(0) == Convert.ToByte('$'))
        {
            data.Remove(data.ElementAt(0));
            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
            {
                listAuido.Add(time, data.ElementAt(0));
                data.Remove(data.ElementAt(0));
            }
            listPulse.Add(time, data.ElementAt(0));
            data.Remove(data.ElementAt(0));
        }
        zgcMasterPane.AxisChange();
    }
    if (remaning > 0)
    {
        data2 = new LinkedList<byte>(Read_Data4);
        data2.Remove(data2.ElementAt(0));
        time = new XDate(DateTime.Now);
        for (int i = 0; i < remaning - 2; i++)
        {
            listAuido.Add(time, data2.ElementAt(0));
            data2.Remove(data2.ElementAt(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `data` is set at the end of "Thread's method".

```
data = new LinkedList<byte>(Read_Data3);//<--assigned here
```

But thread calling this method won't wait till the `thread1` finishes, So you'll get an `ArgumentNullException` in following line.

```
if (data.ElementAt(0) == Convert.ToByte('$'))
```

To fix it, you may need to wait till `thread1` completes.

```
thread1.Start();
thread1.Join();
```

Or just move the following code from that if statement inside the thread's delegate.